# How can I calculate values specific to an ID provided on each line?

Tags: python, r, pandas

I have a data table of values that look like this:

```
Score ID
1.2    1
2.4    1
1.1    1
1.9    1
2.4    2
3.5    2
2.2    2
1.1    3
1.1    3
1.7    3
3.1    3
2.2    3
```

And what I really need is to calculate the Change In Score for each ID in a separate column, such that it looks like this:

```
Score   ID  Changes
1.2     1   
2.4     1   1.2
1.1     1   -1.3
1.9     1   0.8
2.4     2   
3.5     2   1.1
2.2     2   -1.3
1.1     3   
1.1     3   0
1.7     3   0.6
3.1     3   1.4
2.2     3   -0.9
```

Notice how each "changes" is calculated by taking the previous score, and subtracting it from the current score: e.g. in the first changes, you get 1.2 by taking  1.2 = 2.4(current score) - 1.2(The previous score)

The problem is that these scores must only pertain to only the scores within the confines of the ID. You can't just iterate over and take the difference of scores. How would I do this? What logic can I use to test to contain "changes" within the same ID? I'm familiar with R or python (or BASH) to do this.

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: If the scores really look like this then you certainly can just iterate over them, just add an if statement to check if the previous ID is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python using Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
         'Score': [1.2, 2.4, 1.1, 1.9, 2.4, 3.5, 2.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.7, 3.1, 2.2]})

df['Changes'] = df.groupby('ID').Score.transform(lambda group: group.diff())

>>> df
    Score  ID  Changes
0     1.2   1      NaN
1     2.4   1      1.2
2     1.1   1     -1.3
3     1.9   1      0.8
4     2.4   2      NaN
5     3.5   2      1.1
6     2.2   2     -1.3
7     1.1   3      NaN
8     1.1   3      0.0
9     1.7   3      0.6
10    3.1   3      1.4
11    2.2   3     -0.9
```

Comment: Wow, that's very neat. I didn't know there was a specific command df to do that in python

Answer (score 5):

In R maybe:

```
transform(
  df, 
  Changes = ave(df$Score, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
)
#    Score ID Changes
# 1    1.2  1      NA
# 2    2.4  1     1.2
# 3    1.1  1    -1.3
# 4    1.9  1     0.8
# 5    2.4  2      NA
# 6    3.5  2     1.1
# 7    2.2  2    -1.3
# 8    1.1  3      NA
# 9    1.1  3     0.0
# 10   1.7  3     0.6
# 11   3.1  3     1.4
# 12   2.2  3    -0.9
```

`df` holds your original data frame.

---

With regards to @Bulat's comment:

```
id<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
score <-  c(1.2, 2.4, 1.1, 1.9, 2.4, 3.5, 2.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.7, 3.1, 2.2)
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(id, score)
dt = data.table(id, score)
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  dt = dt[ , diff := c(NA, diff(score)), by = id],
  df = df$diff <- ave(df$score, df$id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x))),
  times = 1000
)
# Unit: microseconds
#  expr      min        lq      mean    median        uq      max neval cld
#    dt 1121.931 1225.2660 1342.4626 1269.5530 1321.2210 5908.411  1000   b
#    df  397.175  488.2085  547.8198  525.8175  586.7995 7784.270  1000  a
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's going on in that Changes line. Can you explain it? How does it know to group by ID? Where does that x come from?

Comment: Have a look at [`?ave`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/stats/ave): arguments after the 1st argument may be grouping variables, which is `df$ID` here. The `x` comes from the `function` call. `ave` basically splits the data by `ID`, passes `Score` as `x` to the function, which then calculates the consecutive differences and adds `NA`, because there is no difference for the 1st value. 
It could have also been `df$Changes <- ave(df$Score, df$ID, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))`.

Comment: this seems to be very slow, considering together with the complexity of the syntax I would not do it this way.

Comment: @Bulat `ave` is acually pretty fast - see my edit. And it does not need another package and data structure.

Comment: did you just test it on 10 records?

Answer (score 2):

R with `data.table`:

```
id<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
score <-  c(1.2, 2.4, 1.1, 1.9, 2.4, 3.5, 2.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.7, 3.1, 2.2)
library(data.table)
df = data.table(id, score)

df[ , diff := c(NA, diff(score)), by = id]
```

It is worth mentioning that this is 10x faster compared to the `transform` approach:

```
id<- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
id <- rep(id, 10^5)
score <-  c(1.2, 2.4, 1.1, 1.9, 2.4, 3.5, 2.2, 1.1, 1.1, 1.7, 3.1, 2.2)
score <- rep(score, 10^5)
library(data.table)
dt = data.table(id, score)
df = data.frame(id, score)

library(microbenchmark)
m <- microbenchmark(
  "data.table" = dt[ , diff := c(NA, diff(score)), by = id],
  "transform" = transform(
    df, 
    Changes = ave(df$score, df$id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, diff(x)))
  ), times = 10
)

boxplot(m)
print(m)
# Unit: milliseconds
#      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
# data.table   95.1905  100.3342  111.2434  102.6525  106.7417  151.2913    10
#  transform 1032.3829 1066.3912 1078.5727 1070.9577 1103.4971 1135.7380    10
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` in `R`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   mutate(diff = c(NA, diff(Score)))
#   Score    ID  diff
#   <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#1    1.2     1    NA
#2    2.4     1   1.2
#3    1.1     1  -1.3
#4    1.9     1   0.8
#5    2.4     2    NA
#6    3.5     2   1.1
#7    2.2     2  -1.3
#8    1.1     3    NA
#9    1.1     3   0.0
#10   1.7     3   0.6
#11   3.1     3   1.4
#12   2.2     3  -0.9
```